# Add two 'release' fields on one form (Axosoft onTime tracker)

Tags: ontime

I'm using [Axosoft Ontime](http://www.axosoft.com/ontime) for bug tracking, and have configured several 'release' items under my project.

'Default' (ie. bug) list has a field named 'Release' that displays on forms as a dropbox of all available 'release' items. Fine. I use it as a flag for target release for each bug.

What I'd like to do is add several fields of that type, that would allow me to define, for each bug, a "bug found on this release" and "bug was actually fixed in this release" on top of the original "bug has been scheduled for this release" field.

The bad news is that this 'Release' field comes by default (ie. is not a custom field) (or so I guess) and thus is not accessible through my Tools > Manage > Custom fields.

Do anyone know how I could add other fields of the same type?

(I'm using OnTime 11.0.1, winforms version; but could start using web version if needed)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official OnTime support team answers a radical no (as of v 11.2). Sad but clear.

> OnTime currently supports only 1 release field.  If you would need to
>   store an additional release field you can add a custom text field to
>   enter in the release, or use a custom picklist field.  You however
>   would need to update the pick list with any additional releases in
>   order to update the values when you add a new release.

Since using text fields as they suggest seems a very bad idea (users are free to input incorrect data, release names are not sorted), I will probably have to maintain a gigantic pick list.

Has anyone a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a way, not the kind I would like, though, as it requires hacking the database itself. I haven't tested it so you really should use it with caution.

OnTime supports pick lists that are dependent on a database stored procedure. The trick would be to build a request on Release table and bind a pick list to it.

A (very basic) documentation can be found as podcast on http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqg3GZlx6dc